Issues with GCC / G++ in cuda 11.7
I am having problems with CUDA extension, I've been trying to run several deep learning models that require C. As always the first step with these models is to run setup.py but I keep encountering the same error:
CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['which', '/home/XXX/miniconda3/envs/ENV1/bin/g++']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

I have double checked that I do indeed have g++ and gcc installed:
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_May__3_18:49:52_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0

I have tried to change environments, reinstall all packages to ensure compatibility, re-installed gcc, g++, nvcc multiple times, used the system's nvcc, gcc, g++, all failed.

That error is coming from the setup.py. It has nothing to do with nvcc or CUDA per se. You are instructing the setup.py, whether explicitly or implicitly, to look for the host C++ compiler in a place where it cannot be found. Fix that and you might have more success
